# Conflicting React versions with Turborepo + Docusaurus

Tags: next.js, docusaurus, turborepo

Playing around with this stack, I've setup a new Turborepo (`npx create-turbo@latest`) and replaced the existing `docs` app with a Docusaurus installtion by simply removing the `docs` directory and running `npx create-docusaurus@latest docs classic` within the `apps` directory.

Unfortunately now the Next.js app doesn't work anymore due to:

```
error: Next.js requires react >= 18.2.0 to be installed
```

When running `npm i` I get a bunch of warnings:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency                                   
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency                                                                                                                  
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency                             
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency                                   
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency                                                                                                                  
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency                                                                                                                  
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency                                                                                                                  
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency                                                                                                                  
npm WARN While resolving: @docusaurus/types@2.4.1                                                                                                             
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0                                                                                                                              
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom                                                
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^18.2.0" from next@13.4.6                                                                                                          
npm WARN   node_modules/next                                                                                                                                  
npm WARN     peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.22.1                                                                                                 
npm WARN     node_modules/next-auth                                            
npm WARN     2 more (next-themes, next-template)                                                                                                              
npm WARN   6 more (next-auth, next-themes, next-template, ...)           
npm WARN                                                                       
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:                                                                                                                        
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^18.2.0" from next@13.4.6                                                                                                            
npm WARN node_modules/next                                                                                                                                    
npm WARN   peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.22.1                                                                                                   
npm WARN   node_modules/next-auth                                                                                                                             
npm WARN   2 more (next-themes, next-template)                                                                                                                
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency                                
npm WARN While resolving: @docusaurus/types@2.4.1                                                                                                             
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0                                                                                                                              
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom                                                                                                                               
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^18.2.0" from next@13.4.6
npm WARN   node_modules/next                                                   
npm WARN     peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.22.1         
npm WARN     node_modules/next-auth                                            
npm WARN     2 more (next-themes, next-template)                
npm WARN   6 more (next-auth, next-themes, next-template, ...)        
npm WARN                                                                                                                                                      
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:                                         
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^18.2.0" from next@13.4.6
npm WARN node_modules/next                                                     
npm WARN   peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.22.1
npm WARN   node_modules/next-auth                                              
npm WARN   2 more (next-themes, next-template)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @docusaurus/types@2.4.1
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0                                               
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom                                                
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^18.2.0" from next@13.4.6
npm WARN   node_modules/next                                                   
npm WARN     peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.22.1
npm WARN     node_modules/next-auth                                            
npm WARN     2 more (next-themes, next-template)
npm WARN   6 more (next-auth, next-themes, next-template, ...)
npm WARN                                                                       
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:                                         
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^18.2.0" from next@13.4.6
npm WARN node_modules/next                                                     
npm WARN   peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.22.1
npm WARN   node_modules/next-auth                                              
npm WARN   2 more (next-themes, next-template)
```

Anyone knows how to fix that?